# Convert R code to MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab, translation

r code for an algorithm with fictitious data:
I am working to translate this to MATLAB but struggling with the calculation that's running inside the loop. Any help will be appreciated.

```
data <- c(-0.39, 0.12, 0.94, 1.67, 1.76, 2.44, 3.72, 
       4.28, 4.92, 5.53, 0.06, 0.48, 1.01, 1.68, 1.80, 
       3.25, 4.12, 4.60, 5.28, 6.22) 
pi <- 0.546  
sigmas1 <- 0.87 
sigmas2 <- 0.77 
mu1 <- numeric(0) 
mu2 <- numeric(0) 
r   <- numeric(0) 
R1  <- matrix (0 ,20 ,100) 
mu1[1] <- 4.62 
mu2[1] <- 1.06

for(j in 1:100){
  for ( i in 1:20){
    r [i] <- pi * dnorm (data[i] , mu2[j], sigmas2^(1/2))/((1-    pi)*dnorm(data[i], 
        mu1[j], sigmas1^(1/2))+ pi*dnorm(data[i], mu2[j], sigmas2^(1/2))) 
R1[i, j] <- r[i] 
}
r
mu1[j+1] <- sum((1-r)*data)/sum(1-r)
mu2[j+1] <- sum(r*data)/sum(r) 
Muu1 <- mu1[j+1]
Muu2 <- mu2[j+1]
}

Muu1
Muu2
x11() 
layout(matrix(c(1, 2))) 
plot(mu1, type="l", main="", xlab="EM Iteration for the Fictitious Data")
plot(mu2, type="l", main="", xlab='EM Iteration for the Fictitious Data')
```

Comment: If you need just to run it inside matlab then this should help you http://neurochannels.blogspot.ru/2010/05/how-to-run-r-code-in-matlab.html

Comment: Oh no. I have to translate this into MATLAB and work with a real data as this one only uses fictitious data.

Comment: Why not just learn MATLAB or keep coding in R. Sure you are not thinking about putting all conversion work for all R code to be done by helpful people on SO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "give me the code" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB equivalent of the `dnorm` function of R is [`normpdf`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html). The arguments are the same as in R:

```
normpdf(X,mu,sigma)
```

With that the for loop can easily be adapted. As the `normpdf` function allows vectors as inputs, you can dump the inner for loop and use a vectorized approach instead. Always keep in mind, that `*` and `/` are the matrix multiplication and division in MATLAB. To get element-wise operators, use `.*` and `./` instead.

Note that in MATLAB it is better to preallocate all variables. As `mu1` and `mu2` go from 1 to 100, but in each step you set the value `mu[j+1]`, it will have size `1x101`. For `r`and `R1` the size is clear i think.

All together, this would give the following code:

```
data = [-0.39, 0.12, 0.94, 1.67, 1.76, 2.44, 3.72,...
    4.28, 4.92, 5.53, 0.06, 0.48, 1.01, 1.68, 1.80,...
    3.25, 4.12, 4.60, 5.28, 6.22];

pi=0.546;
sigmas1 = 0.87;
sigmas2 = 0.77; 
mu1 = zeros(1,101);
mu2 = zeros(1,101);
r = zeros(1,20);
R1 = zeros(20,100);
mu1(1) = 4.62;
mu2(1) = 1.06;

for j=1:100
    r= pi*normpdf(data,mu2(j),sigmas2^(1/2)) ./ ...
        ((1-pi)*normpdf(data,mu1(j),sigmas1^(1/2)) + ...
         pi*normpdf(data,mu2(j),sigmas2^(1/2)));
    R1(:,j) = r;
    mu1(j+1) = sum((1-r).*data)/sum(1-r);
    mu2(j+1) = sum(r.*data)/sum(r);
end

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(mu1);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(mu2);
```

If this doesn't work correctly for you, or you have any questions on the code, feel free to comment.

Comment: Worked great hdaderts. I was struggling with reallocation memory for mu1, mu2 and r, was confused between cell() or zeros() and got this message "Attempted to access mu1(2); index out of bounds because numel(mu1)=1". The plot came out great. Thanks much.